# Excel - using wildcard in IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, wildcard, formula

I need to use wildcard in IF formula (see the bold chars)

> =IF(AND($J7243>ANR$23;AND(OR($C7243=**ANP$7&"*";**$C7243=ANP$8;$C7243=ANP$9;$C7243=

What is the right syntax (this syntax does not run)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcards don't work here. Possible solution is instead of:

```
$C7243=ANP$7&"*"
```

Use:

```
LEFT($C7243,LEN(ANP$7))=ANP$7
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept&upvote if my solution solves your problem.